# Floating divs within li not displaying correctly in IE

Tags: html, css

I have an unordered list with list items that contain divs that I need to have a `max-width` on:

```
<div>Some content
    <ul class="myUl">
        <li>
            <div class="dynContent">Some</div><div class="dynContent">dynamic</div><div class="dynContent">content</div><span>Test 1</span><div class="clearFix"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="dynContent">blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</div><div class="dynContent">more</div><div class="dynContent">blah</div><span>Test 2</span><div class="clearFix"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="dynContent">testing</div><div class="dynContent">3</div><div class="dynContent">2</div><span>Test 3</span><div class="clearFix"></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.dynContent
{
    float: left;
    font-size: 13px;
    cursor: default;
    padding: 1px 3px 1px 3px;
    border: 1px solid #C5DBEC;
    margin: 1px 3px 0px 3px;
    max-width: 100px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.clearFix
{
    clear:both;
}
```

This works perfectly in FF and Chrome, but big surprise it doesn't work in IE 8. In IE 8 the list markers are displaying at the spot where I have the div with the class of `clearFix`.

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/uh3Rj/)

Comment: A recommendation: Instead of doing `<div class="clearFix"></div>` do `<br clear="all" />`. It's what I do now. Just an easier way to clear all.

Comment: Instead of float: left; try using display: inline-block; http://jsfiddle.net/uh3Rj/3/

Comment: @SKS If I do that then the list contents aren't vertically aligned like they are with floating.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `float: left;`, Try  `display: inline-block;`.

For alignment same as `div`, add below css for the `span`

```
.myUl li span {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/uh3Rj/4/)

Comment: If I do that then the list contents aren't vertically aligned like they are with floating.

Comment: @xbrady - try playing around with `vertical-align` values to fix that. But for ie6-7 you would also need to replace the divs by spans as they only support `inline-block` on elements that are `inline` by default

Comment: @SKS That is close but the content still isn't centered with the list marker.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
li {clear: both}
```

and get rid of the clearfix divs

And then use [a clearfix method](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=clearfix&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-GB%3aofficial&client=firefox-a) on the `ul`

Answer (score 0):

this will get you fixed:
add this to your styles:

```
.clear_cont {
    min-height:1px;
}

/*-- IE 6 fix --*/
* html .clear_cont, * html .clear_cont {
    height:1px;
}

.clear_cont:after {
    clear:both !important;
    content:".";
    display:block;
    font-size:0;
    height:0;
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

then add the clear_cont class to the li element, there's more to be explained in this example, i'll comeback to this topic when i'll have more time

Comment: forgot to mention, when you add clear_cont class to LI, remove the span.clearFix, it's because clear_cont class is "fixing it" without additional tags

Comment: I don't have the extra div in there anymore but it is still showing up the same way in IE: http://jsfiddle.net/uh3Rj/7/